# Can you label a word as multiple entities in LUIS

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Can a single word have multiple labels in LUIS? The UI doesn't seem to allow it.

Comment: Yes - one word can be detected as multiple entities. What for you need to know this?

Comment: See example I have just received from my test LUIS app: { "query": "apple", "topScoringIntent": {...}, "entities": [{"entity": "apple", "type": "Fuits", "startIndex": 0, "endIndex": 4, .. }, { "entity": "apple", "type": "Apple2", "startIndex": 0, "endIndex": 4 } ] }

Comment: Thanks Ferdinand. My situation is that I have a setting I can change and I can do it as a number or as a percentage, so "set x to 20" or "set x to 20%" are both valid. I want 20 to be both number and percent entity.

Comment: First idea on my mind is to create Regex Entity with pattern: "[\d]+\s*(%|mph)?" This way you may capture "set x to 20%", "set x to 20 %", "set x to 20 mph" and "set x to 20". But perhaps you may [edit] your question and try to describe in more detail what you need with some more examples: input -> expected outcome.